# How to automatically update the details on the html page without refresh

Tags: angular

When I click on the update button the code works successfully the data gets change but I have to refresh the page in order to view the changes.

What can I do in this code so that as soon as I hit enter the first name and last name change is reflected without the need to manually refresh the page.

Profile component `html`

```
    <h3 class="profile-username text-center">{{userDetail.first_name}} {{userDetail.last_name}}</h3>

    //update profile form

    <form method="post" [formGroup]="updateForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="first_name" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" name="last_name" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="First Name">
         </div>
    <button>Update<button>
```

Typescript file

```
export class MyProfileComponent implements OnInit {

//data comes from api with the help of resolver
    constructor(private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService) {
                      activeRoute.data.subscribe((data)=> {
                      this.userDetail = data.key.data;
                    })

//update profile input fields is initialized with the relevant details

ngOnInit() {
   this.updateForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        first_name: [this.userDetail.first_name],
        last_name: [this.userDetail.last_name],
    //api updates the profile on submit
 }

 onSubmit() {
     this.auth.updateUser(this.updateForm.value).subscribe((res)=>{
               console.log(res);
          },(err)=>{
               console.log(err);
          }); 
 }
```

auth service file

```
//Get User Profile
getUserProfile() {
    return this.http.post(this.userProfileApi, null);
}
//Update User
updateUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.updateUserDetailsApiUrl, user);
}
```

resolver service which gets profile data (`this.userDetail` in My profile component)

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private auth: AuthService) { }

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
      if(localStorage.getItem('access_token')){
         return this.auth.getUserProfile();
      }
```

Routing

```
{ 
    path: 'dashboard', 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
    resolve: {"key": ProfileDetailsResolverService}, 
    children: [
        {
             path: '',
             component: DashboardComponent,
        },
        {
            path: 'my-profile', 
            component: MyProfileComponent
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide proper, working example or something. There is such a mess in that code, some unclosed braces, unparsable HTML file it's hard to debug it for real.

Answer (score 0):

Why does the route wield userData? My recommendation:

1st) Store the userData within AuthService. Assign the value in callback of the http method. Why is the get profile even a post?

```
userData: UserData;
loadUserProfile() {
  return this.http.get(this.userProfileApi).subscribe(profile => this.userData = profile);
}
```

2nd) Whereever you need that profile, include it with a get

```
get userData(): UserData {
  return this.auth.userData;
}
```

3rd) I assume you stored the data within the router for any routing purposes.
To decide if a user can access a specific route, please create a Service implementing CanActivate and adjust your approutes.

```
{ path: 'myroute', component: TargetComponent, CanActivate: [YourGuard]}
```

-

```
export class YourGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    return /*your condition*/;
  }
}
```

4th) When updaing the user, again in callback change the stored userData within the AuthService.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that.

First: you can put all of your data in a list and then pass to the HTML. So when you add new data you can directly add in the list with the position then you can see the changes.
[Note: you need an event to do that]

```
let newObj = [firstName: 'abc', lastName: 'def']; 
this.dataList.splice(0, 0, newObj);
```

Second: using `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
  constructor(chngRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(chngRef);
    setInterval(() => {
      this.chngRef.detectChanges()
    }, 4000)
  }
```

it will check after a certain period of time and load the data without refreshing the page.

also check this [URL](https://beyondscheme.com/2016/angular2-discussion-portal) because there are other way also to do that.